# Executing async functions in series

Tags: javascript, node.js, function, asynchronous

I'm trying to put this code into two async functions. I've managed to put the auth check into one already,
but im struggling to put the api call in an async function since it has to write json files.
How can I tell the auth function to run after I finish writing the json files?

```js
var authVal = 2;
var condition1 = 3;
var condition2 = 5;
var condition3 = 8;
const fs = require('fs');
const https = require('https');
const util = require('util');
const read = util.promisify(fs.readFile);
let cmdrName = args.join(' ');
let currTime = new Date().toISOString().slice(0, 19);
cmdrName = cmdrName.toLowerCase();

console.log("\x1b[33m" + message.author.username + "\x1b[37m" + " has used " + "\x1b[33m" + ".auth " + cmdrName);

//api call
const data = new TextEncoder().encode(
    JSON.stringify({ "header": { "appName": "CIABot", "appVersion": "1.0", "isDeveloped": true, "APIkey": "" }, "events": [{ "eventName": "getCommanderProfile", "eventTimestamp": currTime, "eventData": { "searchName": cmdrName } }] })
)

const options = {
    hostname: 'inara.cz',
    port: 443,
    path: '/inapi/v1/',
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        'Content-Length': data.length
    }
}

const req = https.request(options, res => {
    console.log(`statusCode: ${res.statusCode}`);

    res.on('data', d => {
        fs.writeFile('./comms/inaraOutput.json', d, function (err) {
            if (err) throw err;
            console.log("\x1b[32m" + "successfully created " + "\x1b[33m" + "inaraOutput.json");
            console.log("\x1b[37m" + "------");
        });
    });
})

req.on('error', error => {
    console.error(error);
})

req.write(data);
req.end();
//api call ends here

//auth check
var auth = async () => {
    const [json1, json2] =
        await Promise
            .all([
                read("./comms/code.json"),
                read("./comms/inaraOutput.json")
            ])
    let jsonCode = JSON.parse(json1);
    let inaraOutput = JSON.parse(json2);

    //fancy auth logic here
};

auth();
```

Comment: Since it looks like you may be new to asynchronous programming, I would suggest you first select one of [these libraries](https://github.com/request/request/issues/3143) for making an http request.  These all return a promise and they gather the result for you so in only a couple lines of much simpler code, you can call a function to execute your http request that returns a promise.  If you don't use one of these libraries, then you will want to manually promisify `http.request()` which involved manually wrapping it in a promise.

Answer (score 0):

You could wrap all your asynchronous calls in another asyn function and await for the executions to finish before executing the OAuth.

```
async function myFunction(){
    await req.on('error', error => {
        console.error(error);
    })
    
    await req.write(data);
    await req.end();
    auth();   
}
myFunction()
```

Comment: It does absolutely no good to slap an `await` in front of functions that do not return a promise.  So, NONE of your `await`s do anything useful.  `await` ONLY does something useful when you are awaiting a promise.  Sorry, to disappoint, but this is not helpful in any way.

Comment: @jfriend00 to be nitpicky - Inside some `async` function `f`, `await x` is wildly different from `x`, even if `x` is not a promise: (1) it exits early, (2) returns the promise immediately, and (3) only continues the function's execution (after the `await`) on the next tick of the `Promise/await` queue (it is one queue for the both of them). Even if it does not help here, it can be "useful" (as you call it) in some scenarios.

Comment: @Domi - Yeah, yeah, yeah. but being picky here is of no use and if the person writing this answer is this confused about where and how to use `await`, it's not going to help them at all to explain the nuances you are mentioning (which are irrelevant to this particular situation).  None of the `awaits` in this function do anything useful here.